# Searching for words in Multi-Dimension Array,Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, cpu-word

I want to search for words in a Word Puzzle in Java. 
The search,as stated is in horizontal,vertical and Diagonal.
I created an Array, but I just don't know how to create a String, and search for words in my String. I need to know how can I have a String that keeps all the values of the table, and how can I be able to type a word, and search for it here.

I know that the search of the words is done with indexOf Function,but I don't know how to perform it.
    import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int IntegerPosition;
        int IntegerPosition2;
        String position="";
        String word="";
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String content="";
        String[][] sopa = {
                {"X","F","E","K","J","U","I","R","S","H"}, 
                {"Z","H","S","W","E","R","T","G","O","T"},
                {"B","R","A","B","F","B","P","M","V","U"}, 
                {"D","W","E","R","O","O","J","L","L","W"},
                {"U","T","O","N","I","R","O","B","C","R"},
                {"O","P","R","O","V","I","I","K","V","B"},
                {"N","I","Q","U","E","N","T","N","S","A"},
                {"O","V","U","L","R","O","S","S","O","T"},
                {"A","S","A","X","J","T","R","R","I","T"},
                {"R","K","M","E","P","U","B","O","T","A"}
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < sopa[0].length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < sopa[i].length; j++){
                content += sopa[i][j];
            }
            System.out.println(content);
            content = "";
        }
        System.out.println("Type the word you are looking for");
        word = s.next();

        for (int i = 0; i < sopa[0].length-1; i++){//t1.length
            for(int j = 0; j < sopa[i].length-1; j++){


            }
        }
        System.out.println(content);
        content = "";
    }

}
```

Comment: Show any attempt to solve this yourself and we will try to guide to towards the right direction.

Comment: Very nice reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795383/how-to-traverse-though-a-2d-char-array-searching-for-words-in-java

Answer (score 0):

First, you should declare what "finding a word" means. I guess you want to find the sequence of letters in each row and column. What about diagonal? Backwards? Wrapping around?

Two solutions come to mind:

1. Use a String index:

   - Build a String of all characters. This needs to be done for each direction (horizontal, vertical, diagonal), but only in the forward order if you reverse the search term for backwards search. For an efficient implementation [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) is your friend.
   - Use [String.indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) to find occurences of the term in your index. Finally you have to calculate row and column from the String position and, if wrapping is not allowed, check if the word crosses any row/column boundary.
   - I'd use this if I had to look for many terms.
2. Use the array

   - Also for each direction (horizontal, vertical, diagonal)
   - Look for occurences of the search term's first letter in your array (by simple iteration). Note that you can stop when the term would not fit the row/column, so for a 6-letter word, you can skip the 5 last rows/columns.
   - If you found an anchor (i.e. matching letter), check the subsequent letters of the word. Cancel on mismatch, otherwise you have found an occurence.

For a more sophisticated matching implementation, the [Boyer-Moore algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) may be of interest.